# JQuery code to hide submit button, within a form, after the form submit button is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I need help with an assignment in my web programming course.  The assignment asks me to use JQuery script code to hide a submit button within a form, located in an HTML file.  All of my references only utilize a single button (not located within a form).
Here is the code for the form:

```
<form id="myForm" action="" onsubmit="" method="get">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Hide Me" id="hideMe">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("input").click(function(event {
    (this).hide();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: @HappyAnt has addressed the issues in your code in their excellent answer below, however for future reference I'd guide you towards the jQuery documentation, which shows the correct syntax and formatting to use: https://api.jquery.com/click

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
$("#hideMe").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).hide();
});
</script>
```

This hides your submit button on click. There was a bracket missing in your code. And you have to disable the button's default behavior which would (with your provided code) submit form data, which would reload the page, where it would be visible again.

I used the button's id as a selector because with more inputs this script would hide everything when you use the general "input" selector.